# Apply function only for specific post

Tags: functions, filters

I have a function to change the locale of the posts

```
function change_og_locale( $locale ) {
    return 'es_ES';
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_locale', 'change_og_locale' );
```

Now, I would like to fire it only if the post has a certain ID. I've tried with

```
function change_og_locale($locale ) {
    if ( $post_id == 52397 ) {
        return 'es_ES';
    }
    return $locale;
}
add_filter('wpseo_locale', 'change_og_locale');
```

But it seems not working

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that to check the post_id the function is `is_single`

```
function change_my_locale($locale ) {
    if ( is_single(52397) ) {
        return 'es_ES';
    }
    return $locale;
}
add_filter('locale', 'change_my_locale');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the `post ID` within the `change_og_locale` function, you need to use the WordPress global variable `$post` or the `get_the_ID()` function to retrieve the current post ID

```
function change_og_locale($locale) {
    global $post; // Access the global $post variable
    
    if (is_singular() && $post->ID == 52397) {
        return 'es_ES';
    }
    
    return $locale;
}
add_filter('wpseo_locale', 'change_og_locale');
```